# Executing bash script with spawn node.js method returns errors

Tags: node.js, spawn

I cannot find a way to execute my node command with spawn method. My script is :

```
node node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --port 8081 --content-base app
```

I tried to execute it like :

```
spawn('node', ['node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --port 8081 --content-base app']);
```

this returns an error

```
Cannot find module '/Users/myuser/code/gui/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --port 8081 --content-base app'
```

I also tried this :

```
spawn('node', ['node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server',' --port 8081 ', '--content-base app']);
```

it runs my webpack server but it doesn't take the `port` and `content-base` params into account. For this case the error is :

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module ' --port 8081 '
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Oh, and I forgot to add that the script runs well with the `exec` method.

Comment: try with '--port=8081'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra spaces in your second argument in the second example. Try this:

```
const args = [
  'node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server',
  '--port',
  '8081',
  '--content-base',
  'app'
];
spawn('node', args);
```

Comment: this would work only if port is number not string,  ```'--port', 8081, '--content-base',```